# Why parallel computing helps the use of non-local resources?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing

I've been reading about parallel computing and it's obvious how it helps saving time and solving larger problems, but I don't get how it takes advantage of the use of non-local resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Better ask IF, before next asking WHY:

With all due respect, the answer for the **IF** is not granted at all.

Any, and here let me emphasise that **before ANY** attempt to change a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** code-execution scheduling into any form of either "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** or even true-**`[PARALLEL]`** **first collect sufficient quantitative evidence** that such efforts will bring an expected set of performance benefits.

This is not obvious and not every professional designer starts with comparing apples to apples.

---

### There are costs to be paid, ALWAYS:

If speaking about using resources, always start with accounting all the costs, that such a use accrues - be it a local or non-local resource. NUMA-architectures have brought many surprises once costs-of-use are indeed accounted for.

[**In modern criticism** of the original Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) formulation one has to decode a principal must to also include all the add-on overhead costs, as the original -- ***overhead-ignorant*** or ***overhead-naive*** if one may wish to -- Amdahl's Law formulation was immensely misleading.

The next cardinal vector of the contemporary criticism of the original law formulation comes from the fact that the block of the yet `[PAR]`-convertible part of the problem processing is not infinitely divisible, but exhibits some sort of further indivisible "atomic"-part, that will never benefit from the next available free resources ( even if such resources are in *almost* infinite capacity ), that could be used for parallel processing, but the "atomically"-indivisible part cannot be further split, as its internal dependency-chain cannot be split and/or distributed.

There are not many problems, that enjoy above 90% `[PARALLEL]`-fraction, so always keep in mind the even overhead-naive formulation demonstration glass-ceiling for the expected acceleration - reaching **`< 10x` for even infinite amount of processors** ( plus check both the parts of the criticism of the original law formulation ). On the very contrary, each and every improvement in the `[SERIAL]`-fraction of the process will always 1:1 influence the gain in performance.

[image]

---

### Answer:

So, **IF** has been validated first that some non-local resource can help **more**, than has to be and always will be paid ( in a sum of all the types of the add-on costs ) for a chance to use of such a distributed-system parallel-processing non-local resource, then **WHY NOT**.

Understanding the Economy-of-Use rules the game.